# How much daily email can be sent using a scratch org?

Tags: email, salesforcedx, singleemailmessage

How much daily email can be sent using a scratch org? Is it governed by number of messages, number of recipients, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The primary limit on scratch org email sending is a limit on the Maximum Daily Email Recipients for Free and Trial Orgs of 50.

Scratch orgs have a status of Trial (I believe this applies to all Developer Edition orgs, but I'm not certain)

There are other limits on email, such as the maximum size of attachments, but when I have seen my scratch orgs stop sending email it has invariably been because I hit this limit of 50.

Comment: While I haven't actively checked this on a scratch org, if the recipient email address is associated with a User then you can send as many emails to the User as you like. It does require use of the User ID as the target object ID...